# Exception Hierarchy with C#

Tags: c#, exception

is there any technical guide for how an Exception Hierarchy is designed with C#?

Comment: check this post by code project : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Exception_CSharp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains Resharper has a very nice feature to create a hierarchical tree of a given type (Type hierarchy Ctrl+Alt+H on IntelliJ keyboard theme), it might be useful.